# Android: Provide a resource if width is smaller than specific DP

Tags: android, android-resources

How do I use the resource qualifiers system in Android to specify that I want a resource to apply only if the width is smaller than a particular value?

To elaborate, suppose I want to provide one layout whenever the current available width is up to - say 320dp - and another layout for all other cases. This is what comes to mind:

```
layout-w320dp/mylayout.xml
layout/mylayout.xml
```

However, as per my understanding of the [resource matching algorithm](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch), even a large device (say, a tablet in landscape) qualifies as `w320dp` - because, well, the available width would be greater than 320dp.

As such, the resource from `layout-w320dp` would **always** be picked - even for larger phones and tablets. The only time the default resource from the `layout` folder is picked is if the available width is *less than* 320dp.

So, how do I express a "smaller than" relationship using the Android resource matching system?

Comment: I do not think you can do it specifically. You do all the larger than ones and what is left over is your smaller. Interested to know if there is another solution

Comment: If you want to use same layout use `layout-w400dp`.

Answer (score 7):

Ugh! Just after posting the question I realized that one way to do this would be to negate the equation - i.e.:

```
layout-w320dp/mylayout.xml --> layout for screens larger than 320dp
layout/mylayout.xml  --> layout for up to 320dp
```

However, I'm still interested in knowing if the original "smaller than" relation can be achieved since it makes the intent much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
float dpHeight = metrics.heightPixels / density;
float dpWidth  = metrics.widthPixels / density;

if(dpWidth >= 360){
    //change your resource      
}
```

Comment: This will work but the question was about using the framework resource qualifier system to achieve this.

Comment: Well dividing the pixels by the device density will return you the density/pixel which actually corresponds to the result of your framework. I'm no aware Android system has such a framework since they already managing it within the system by the resource folder names.